# How to store 100 million integers in a Java array?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, integer

I am working on a small task where I am required to store around 1 billion integers in an Array. However, I am running into a heap space problem. Could you please help me with this?

Machine Details : Core 2 Duo Processor with 4 GB RAM. I have even tried -Xmx 3072m . Is there any work around for this? 
**The same thing works in C++ , so there should definitely be a way to store this many numbers in memory.**

Below is the code and the exception I am getting :

```
public class test {
    private static int C[] = new int[10000*10000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()); 

    }

}
```

Exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at test.(test.java:3)

Comment: We need more information to answer this question... Are those integers random? What is their range? Does their order matter? Can they be repeated?

Comment: You know about `java -mx` right?

Comment: @MiserableVariable: to store 1 billion `int`s you need about 4GB of heap space. That is not always available...

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650274/handle-large-data-structure-in-java

Comment: For that amount of `int` values, you will need 64 bit address space, so are you using 64 bit JVM?

Comment: Almost all responses here lean towards a way to store your data more efficiently and that's because it's highly possible that what you are trying to accomplish can be done without actually storing all 1 billion numbers simultaneously in memory. If you share details on access patterns of your data, you may get more meaningful responses.

Comment: Hm, your current test case (with `10000 * 10000`, i.e. 100 million integers) works with `-Xmx600m` on my system....

Comment: `new int[10000*10000];` is 400MB.You should have no problem without modifying the java heap.

Answer (score 5):

Use an associative array. The key is an integer, and the value is the count (the number of times the integer has been added to the list).

This should get you some decent space savings if the distribution is relatively random, much more so if it's not.

Comment: Good idea. Really, it should be many repetitive values in the array of this size.

Comment: @Dave: a Hashtable, at least as implemented in the Java libraries is one of the worst methods w.r.t. space efficiency. Your approach would only make sense when you have a only few integers with high appearance frequency...

Comment: @Dave: that's the point: most associative arrays have a significant overhead per-entry. Unless a lot of the integers are repeated, a primitive `int[]` may still be better...

Comment: @thkala: it's only better until you run out of space :)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to store 1 billion completely random integers then I am afraid that you really do need to corresponding space, i.e. about 4GB of memory for 32-bit `int` numbers. You can try increasing the JVM heap space but you need to have a 64-bit OS and at least as much physical memory - and there is only so far that you can go.

On the other hand, you might be able to store those number more efficiently if you can make use of specific constraints within your application.

E.g. if you only need to know if a specific `int` is contained in a set, you could get away with a bit set - i.e. a single bit for each value in the `int` range. That is about 4 billion bits, i.e. 512 MB - a far more reasonable space requirement. For example, a handful of [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) objects could cover the whole 32-bit integer range without you having to write any bit-handling code...

Comment: RAM is not the only memory we have. There is also swap.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas: yes, but as far as I know, the JVM will absolutely refuse to allocate more heap that what is available as physical RAM...

Comment: I am not convinced. Where have you seen this documented? Difference between RAM and swap kind of should be transparent for the program. But probably will be slow.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas: Sorry, this indeed does seem to be the case in modern JVMs. My JVM will happily start with `-Xmx80g` which is actually more than both RAM+swap on my system...

Comment: Of course, depending on what one is doing with all those `int`s, using swap space might be little better than doing the computations by hand :-)

Answer (score 2):

May be using memory mapped files will help? They are not allocated from the heap.
Here is an article how to create a matrix. An array should be easier.

[Using a memory mapped file for a huge matrix - Peter Lawrey](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-memory-mapped-file-huge)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase to 4GB on a 32 bit system. 
If you're on a 64 bit system you can go higher.

Type in cmd this

```
java -Xmx4g programname
```

Comment: the address space of a 32-bit process is only 2GB (3GB with large address aware enabled)

Answer (score 0):

As array so big may not fit into your RAM, you need to configure the sufficient HDD swap space. 4 - 16 Gb on swap do not look like something unrealistic at these times.

Java only allows to use `int` as an index of array, not `long`. Hence the largest possible array could have 2147483648 values, enough.

Use `-Xmx` to raise the memory ceiling that by default will probably be insufficient. 3072m is not enough as one billion ints requires about 4 Gb. As space is needed also for the operating system and the like, that machine with 4 Gb RAM cannot hold all 4 Gb data structure in memory.

JRE or OS may also refuse to grant an piece of memory so big in one go, requiring to allocate in some smaller chunks (maybe array or arrays).